# How can i replace table name in sql query with php

Tags: php, regex

How can i replace table name in this query string with another string or table name with php

```
SELECT 
    Panel.Id as PanelId,Panel.Title as PanelTitle,Panel.Icon as PanelIcon,
    SubPanel.Id as SubPanelId,SubPanel.Title as SubPanelTitle,
    SubPanel.Icon as SubPanelIcon,SecurityAccess.Id as Access,SecurityAccess.Controller,
    SecurityAccess.Action
FROM Panel
INNER JOIN SubPanel
INNER JOIN SecurityAccess
WHERE 
Panel.Id > 0 AND SubPanel.Panel = Panel.Id AND SubPanel.Id = UsersAccess.Subpanel
and SubPanel.Id > 0
ORDER BY Panel._Order,SubPanel._Order
```

For example: replace "Panel" with "my_panel"

I do not want you to change my  String.
Just use this string as it exists.

Comment: Which table name? Would you not also have to replace all the columns in that table as well? Maybe a little more detail from you would be helpful!

Comment: Sry, I added a little more explanation

Comment: If you don't want to **CHANGE** the string , how would you **CHANGE** the table name in the string?

Comment: I mean, you can not change the string of the user. After you receive the user's string, you can change it dynamically.

Comment: Well, then you need a regex solution, I suggest adding regex tag to your question.

Comment: @Accountant م Thnak you

Comment: @shahinataei you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you..

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            $table_1.Id as PanelId, $table_1.Title as PanelTitle, $table_1.Icon as PanelIcon,
            $table_2.Id as SubPanelId, $table_2.Title as SubPanelTitle,
            $table_2.Icon as SubPanelIcon, $table_3.Id as Access, $table_3.Controller,
            $table_3.Action
        FROM $table_1
        INNER JOIN $table_2
        INNER JOIN $table_3
        WHERE 
        $table_1.Id > 0 AND $table_2.Panel = $table_1.Id AND $table_2.Id = UsersAccess.Subpanel
        and $table_2.Id > 0
        ORDER BY $table_1._Order, $table_2._Order";
```

for your current query
it would be like..

```
$table_1 = "Panel";
$table_2 = "SubPanel";
$table_3 = "SecurityAccess";
```

If $table_ vars are user input than be careful to escape them before putting into query.

Comment: Could make that easier to read if you remember that `$var` in a double quoted string will be automatically get expanded. So you could remove a lot of that stop/start concatenation

Comment: Unfortunately no, think that this has been sent to you by a user. And it is supposed to change the name of the user-selected tables by the name of the table you want

Comment: yeah for sure.. @RiggsFolly

Comment: _think that this has been sent to you by a user_ WOW, thats got to be in the top 10 bad ideas ever

Comment: @RiggsFolly This was just an example

Comment: @RiggsFolly The user can be a programmer working with the app.

Comment: I know @RiggsFolly I am suggesting this as this vars would be set and defined by OP, and if the vars will be user input than it should be definitely escaped.

Comment: @shahinataei In that case, How would you know what table name this potential hacker was using, and therefore what table name needed changing to the correct table name!?!?!?!?!?

Comment: You can create an array of your table names and create an if condition if user input table name is in array than only execute the query.